# Rounding a Formula Field

Tags: formula-field, rounding

I have a formula field that is returns a currency and is set to 2 decimals. It displays fine, but when I access the field through the API it returns 6 decimals.

> 12.493587 should round to 12.49
>
> 15.516359 should round to 15.52

Of course I tried a ROUND function with no success. I fixed similar problems in APEX code, but in this case I do not want to use APEX since I am trying to keep it simple.

I found an [article](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2012/11/salesforce-and-decimal-places/) that shows the problem I am having and suggests to round it when I pull it from the API. I do not want to transform data on my API calls.

Is there any other solutions to this?

Comment: You said you tried the ROUND function, with no success. Can you elaborate on what didn't work in that case, and maybe post the formula?

Comment: Thanks @Carolyn but I end up populating a custom field using an APEX trigger and rounding the result with APEX code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different rounding types for `Decimal`s.

`Decimal.round(System.RoundingMode)` ==> 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Decimal_round_2.htm

`System.RoundingMode` ==>
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_decimal_rounding_mode.htm

`Decimal` class ==>
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm

Answer (score 0):

We have a formula element of datatype currency in a flow which was defined "MyRecord.MyOldPrice * 1.047" . The element specified two decimal places, but when we assigned the formula's value to MyRecord.MyNewPrice, it stored three decimal places. We changed the formula to "ROUND( MyRecord.MyOldPrice * 1.047, 2)" , now it stores a two-decimal-place value, as we want. It seems the implementation of the decimal-places attribute is broken. Perhaps the use of the three-decimal-place constant confuses the system.